# multiple indexing with imakeidx : auhtor's names only

Tags: biblatex, indexing, imakeidx

I am writing my dissertation in `yathesis` class and want to produce multiple indexes with `imakeindex` package. I have been able to produce two indexes: an index of names with title subentries, and an index of titles organized by year. From there, I cannot produce is an index of author's names (removing titles).

Would someone know how I can get an index of names only?

If possible, with the surname of the author followed by the first letter of his first name in parenthesis. 
Like that: **Skocpol (T.),**

Many thanks !

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{yathesis}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage[main=french]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authortitle,autolang=hyphen,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\makeindex
\makeindex[name=name-title,title={Name and Title Index}]
\makeindex[name=year-title,title={Year and Title Index}]

\makeatletter
\@ifpackageloaded{biblatex_legacy}
{\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:title}{%
    \iffieldundef{title}
    {\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name-title]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}
    {\usebibmacro{index:name:title}{\index[name-title]}{#1}{#3}{#5}{#7}}}}
{\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:title}{%
        \iffieldundef{title}
        {\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name-title]}
            {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{index:name:title}{\index[name-title]}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiven}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffix}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{with:year}{%
\iffieldundef{year}
{\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[year-title]}{%
        \mkbibindexentry{0}{Not dated}%
        \subentryoperator%
        \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#1}}}}
{\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[year-title]}{%
        \thefield{year}\subentryoperator%
        \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#1}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
\ifciteindex
{\indexnames[name:title]{labelname}%
    \indexfield[with:year]{indextitle}}
{}}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

Here is some text avec un ballon\index{ballon}
\autocite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d}
\autocite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics}

 \backmatter 

 \clearpage

 \printbibliography

 \raggedright
 \printindex
 \printindex[name-title] % the name-title index
 \printindex[year-title] % the year-title index

 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following creates an extra index with names only and formats all names produced by `biblatex` in the index in the "Family (G.)" format.

To change the name format we redefine `\mkbibindexname`. For the name-only index we can mainly copy things from the other indices, but use `name:index` instead of `index:name` instead of `index:name:title`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=french]{babel}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[indexing=cite,style=authortitle,autolang=hyphen,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=name-only,title={Name Index}]
\makeindex[name=name-title,title={Name and Title Index}]
\makeindex[name=year-title,title={Year and Title Index}]


\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:title}{%
  \iffieldundef{title}
    {\usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name-title]}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiveni}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}
    {\usebibmacro{index:name:title}{\index[name-title]}
       {\namepartfamily}
       {\namepartgiveni}
       {\namepartprefix}
       {\namepartsuffix}}}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{name:only}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[name-only]}
    {\namepartfamily}
    {\namepartgiveni}
    {\namepartprefix}
    {\namepartsuffix}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\mkbibindexname}[4]{%
  \ifuseprefix
    {\ifdefvoid{#3}{}{#3 }%
     \@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{ (#2)}%
     \actualoperator
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{\MakeCapital{#3} }%
     #1%
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{  (#2)}}
    {\@firstofone #1% remove spurious braces
     \ifdefvoid{#4}{}{ #4}%
     \ifdefvoid{#2}{}{ (#2)}%
     \ifdefvoid{#3}{}{ #3}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{with:year}{%
  \iffieldundef{year}
    {\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[year-title]}{%
       \mkbibindexentry{0}{Not dated}%
       \subentryoperator%
       \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#1}}}}
    {\usebibmacro{index:entry}{\index[year-title]}{%
       \thefield{year}\subentryoperator%
       \mkbibindexfield{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#1}}}}}

\renewbibmacro*{citeindex}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexnames[name:only]{labelname}%
     \indexnames[name:title]{labelname}%
     \indexfield[with:year]{indextitle}}
    {}}

\begin{document}
  Here is some text avec un ballon\index{ballon}
  \autocite{knuth:ct,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:c,knuth:ct:d}
  \autocite{aristotle:anima,aristotle:poetics,aristotle:physics}

 \printindex
 \printindex[name-title] % the name-title index
 \printindex[year-title] % the year-title index
 \printindex[name-only] % the name index
 \end{document}
```

[image]