# Removing emphasis from Xindy title index entries

Tags: indexing

**Problem:** I am creating author, title and subject indexes using `imakeidx`, `biblatex` with `indexing=true` and Xindy. The indexes are being created properly but the title index contains the entries in italics which I do not want. I found code from answers by [Moewe](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/443260/245306) and [manueltts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/507643/245306) that I adadpted to my documents needs.

**What I have tried:** I tried to negate the `\emph` with another `\emph` like this:

```
\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{\emph #1}}
```

But the result from using this (in my main file) doesn't work consistently:

[image]

**What I would like:** The `\emph` command being wrote after `\item` in the `titles.ind` file to be negated or not inserted in the first place. It would be nice to know what process is causing the `\emph` to be added too as I cannot see where it is coming from.

**MWEB:**

```
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: xindy: {modules: [basic], codepage: utf8, language: english}
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes, options: [-halt-on-error]}}
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}

\begin{filecontents*}{style.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex} ~n
 \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
 \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
 \par\textbf{\large#1}\par\medskip
   \nopagebreak
  }"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", ")
;; End
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,indexing=true,natbib=true,safeinputenc=true,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeindex[title={Subject Index},program=truexindy, options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L english -M style]
\makeindex[title={Author Index}, program=truexindy, options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L english -M style, name=names]
\makeindex[title={Title Index},     program=truexindy, options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L english -M style, name=titles]

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121560/245306
\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
   \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
     {\namepartfamily}
     {\namepartgiven}
     {\namepartprefix}
     {\namepartsuffix}}

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\index{test}\index{actual}\cite{doody,bertram,gillies,glashow}

\printbibliography

\begingroup
\idxlayout{columns=3}
\printindex[names]
\endgroup

\begingroup
\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex[titles]
\endgroup

\begingroup
\idxlayout{columns=3}
\printindex
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

**How it currently looks:**

The title index currently looks like this:

[image: italicIndex]

The `titles.ind` file being generated contains the following:

```
\begin{theindex} 

 \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
 \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
 \par\textbf{\large#1}\par\medskip
   \nopagebreak
  }
  \lettergroup{G}
  \item \emph  {Gromov invariants for holomorphic maps on {Riemann} surfaces}\dotfill \hyperpage{1}, \hyperpage{2}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{H}
  \item \emph  {Hemingway's Style and {Jake's} Narration}\dotfill \hyperpage{1}, \hyperpage{2}
  \item \emph  {Herder and the Preparation of {Goethe's} Idea of World Literature}\dotfill \hyperpage{1}, \hyperpage{2}

  \indexspace

  \lettergroup{P}
  \item \emph  {Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions}\dotfill \hyperpage{1}, \hyperpage{2}

\end{theindex}
```

I would appreciate any advice on how to remove the emphasis, I cannot work out what function or process is causing the `\emph` to be added to the `titles.ind` file. Apologies if this has been asked before, I couldn't find an answer after a decent bit of searching. I am certain I am using Xindy wrong with `arara` and `makeindex` but it compiles correctly so must be okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears my

> decent bit of searching

was insufficient. From the `biblatex.def` file [found on GitHub, lines 1185-1194](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/dev/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def), the indexing commands are located and the issue is with this line of code:

```
\newbibmacro*{index:title}[2]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:field}{#1}{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{\emph{#2}}}
```

This should be edited if `\emph`'s removal is desired as such:

```
\renewbibmacro*{index:title}[2]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:field}{#1}{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{#2}}
```

The new file produces this output as desired:

[image]

Updated MWEB:

```
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}
% arara: xindy: {modules: [basic], codepage: utf8, language: english}
% arara: lualatex: {shell: yes, options: [-halt-on-error]}}
% arara: lualatex: {options: [-halt-on-error]}

\begin{filecontents*}{style.xdy}
(markup-index :open  "\begin{theindex} ~n
 \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
 \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
 \par\textbf{\large#1}\par\medskip
   \nopagebreak
  }"
          :close "~n~n\end{theindex}~n"
          :tree)

(markup-locclass-list :open "\dotfill " :sep ", ")
;; End
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage[backend=biber,indexing=true,natbib=true,safeinputenc=true,style=numeric]{biblatex}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeindex[title={Subject Index},program=truexindy, options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L english -M style]
\makeindex[title={Author Index}, program=truexindy, options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L english -M style, name=names]
\makeindex[title={Title Index},     program=truexindy, options=-M texindy -C utf8 -L english -M style, name=titles]

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{default}{%
   \usebibmacro{index:name}{\index[names]}
     {\namepartfamily}
     {\namepartgiven}
     {\namepartprefix}
     {\namepartsuffix}}

\DeclareIndexFieldFormat{indextitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{index:title}{\index[titles]}{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{index:title}[2]{%
  \usebibmacro{index:field}{#1}{\thefield{indexsorttitle}}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\index{test}\index{actual}\cite{doody,bertram,gillies,glashow}

\printbibliography

\begingroup
\idxlayout{columns=3}
\printindex[names]
\endgroup

\begingroup
\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex[titles]
\endgroup

\begingroup
\idxlayout{columns=3}
\printindex
\endgroup

\end{document}
```